# Get size of all files in directory modified within last year

Tags: linux, file-search, date-modified

I'm trying to evaluate storage usage on a linux server.

Most of the bulk of storage is coming from the images. I'd like to see if I can get a sense of the size of files modified in the last year. and maybe also the last 5 years, to see how that compares to the total size of the images directory (which is 40GB)

I have tried `du -h` and that is handy, but I cannot see how to filter those results by modified date.

Answer (score 4):

If the [num-utils](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) package is installed, [`numsum`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/numsum.1.html) provides an easy way to add many numbers; while `numfmt` simplifies the output:

```
find . -type f -mtime -365 -printf '%s\n' | numsum | numfmt --to=iec
```

(`find` code borrowed from [Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister](https://superuser.com/a/1074690/582419).)

For the last **5** years do:

```
find . -type f -mtime -$((365 * 5)) -printf '%s\n' | numsum | numfmt --to=iec
```

*If* an accurate day count is needed, `date` will provide that.  Here's a shell function that returns the *exact* number of days in the last *n* years:

```
# covert Last _n_ Years to Days
# usage:  ly2d n
ly2d() \
    { echo $(( \
               $(( `date -d today +%s` - \
                   `date -d $1" years ago" +%s` )) \
           / 60 / 60 / 24 )) ; \
    }
```

Using `ly2d` for the last **5** years:

```
find . -type f -mtime -$(ly2d 5) -printf '%s\n' | numsum | numfmt --to=iec
```

Comment: i seem to not have numfmt available. does that require a different library?

Comment: Debian's _coreutils_ package has _numfmt_, or check the [upstream source](http://gnu.org/software/coreutils).   If that fails, remove the `numfmt`, the sum would then be in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl to sum the output of find:

```
find . -type f -mtime -365 -printf '%s\n' |\
  perl -e 'my $s=0; while(<>) { $s += $_; } print "$s\n"'
```

Comment: If the _num-utils_ package is installed, _numsum_ is simpler than all that _perl_:  `find . -type f -mtime -365 -printf '%s\n' | numsum`

Comment: Appending `| numfmt --to=iec` helps too.

Comment: @agc You should post it as an answer, no reason not to. I would happily upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach has the benefit relying only on common utilities `du` and `find`, which are available out of the box on pretty much all Linuxes.

```
du -hc $(find . -type f -mtime -365)
```

This works by finding all of the modified files using `find`, then passing all those files to `du` to calculate the sizes.  The `-c` option ensures a summed total is printed at the end.